# Comparing two solutions of the first part of 3.2.2 in Allen Hatcher Alg. Top.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Here is the question I am trying to compare two solutions of it:

Using the cup product $H^k(X, A;R) \times H^l(X,B;R) \to H^{k+l}(X, A\cup B;R),$ show that if $X$ is the union of contractible open subsets $A$ and $B,$ then all cup products of positive-dimensional classes in $H^*(X;R)$ are zero.

Here is the first solution:

> [image]

**My concerns about it is as follows:**

I think I understand this solution, and nothing bothers me in it (Hopefully it is correct, **let me know if there are typos that I missed in it please**)

Here is the second solution:

> [image]

**My questions about it are:**

What exactly this author is doing? Why using excision? Why he is proving using cochains?

Could someone help me answer these questions please?

Comment: I don't know what the notation $H^\ast(X;A+B)$ refers to, but the solution mentions that isomorphism $H^\ast(X;A+B)\cong H^\ast(X;A\cup B)$ follows from excision. As for the rest: It seems that the second solution proves that cup products are well-defined for pairs of spaces (not just for single) spaces. I guess this is included since Hatcher does not really prove it in his book. Apart from that the solutions are the same.